# How to use built in designer widget Icons for subclassed widgets in pyqt5

Tags: pyqt

I've built lots of custom widgets to be used in Qt Designer, lots are just sub-classed standard widgets and I would like to use the standard icon. I can't find any reference to them nor could I actually find them on my system. If you leave out the icon function in the designer custom widget plugin, it will use a generic QT icon but that's it.

Comment: Well you can simply capture and save those "standard" icons to use within your "custom" widgets but frankly the "standard" icons are not really standard they are what they are for the OS you are operating upon and software you are using.  So to implement the icons you want you should really define those and most of those can be found online somewhere and/or on you computer since you cannot display an icon without having it present somewhere.  Just go to your root drive and search for *.ico that should find them all assuming they are Icons and not jpegs, pngs, etc...

Comment: what are *designer widget icons*?

Comment: When using Qt's Designer each widget is represented by an icon in the selection side bar. I wish to reuse them for widgets I have that are similar. In GTK/GLADE  IIRC it automatically uses the icon you subclassed your widget from or you can apply a custom one. I want to use the standard designer ones and am surprised that thee is no way to do this.